# 2-in-1 (detachable keyboard) for office work with good multitasking ability

Tags: pc, tablet

1. Enough RAM/processor for multitasking (mainly Office + multitab internet surfing)
2. Preferably Android system
3. supports 3g
4. Budget (up to 300 euros, a little bit more would be fine)